# Can a child component render its parent content only?

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, aws-amplify

I'm extending a parent component that is part of an SDK (AWS Amplify - SignIn), which I have no control over. I only need to make a small change where the input field data will be modified to be lowercase before it's passed to the authentication function.

```
import React from "react";
import { SignIn } from "aws-amplify-react";

export class CustomSignIn extends SignIn {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._validAuthStates = ["signIn", "signedOut", "signedUp"];
  }

  showComponent(theme) {
    return (
      <div>My child component that I don't need to render</div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomSignIn;
```

This is more of a general question not specifically related to AWS Amplify, but I'd like to use the existing UI / rendering code from the parent — is there a way to simply display the parent's rendering content and not have any child content?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a component and use that components render function.

```
class ComponentFromThirdParty extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>This is ComponentFromThirdParty</div>;
  }
}

class MyComponent extends ComponentFromThirdParty {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(
      "MyComponent was mounted and I render the same as ComponentFromThirdParty"
    );
  }
  render() {
    return super.render();
  }
}
```

`MyComponent` will render this when mounted.

`This is ComponentFromThirdParty`